# Check for empty array using JPA Criteria query

Tags: java, jpa

I have a legacy database in which there are classes that have fields that are arrays rather than collections, i.e.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COM_DR_TARGET")
public class Target {
    // ...
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "COM_TARGET_INDICES",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TARGET_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID"))
    @Column(name = "PIXEL_TABLE_INDICES")
    private int[] pixelTableIndices;
    // ...
}
```

I'm using the JPA metamodel API, so I can refer to the field as Target_.pixelTableIndices .

Here's my problem:

I want one of the query conditions to be that the array cannot be zero-length and I can't for the life of me figure out how to express that with the JPA Criteria API.

Any advice would be extremely welcome.